# Gatsby & GraphQL - render a download link from a queried file

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, graphql-js

I'm building a static website with Gatsby and I need to put some .txt or .pdf files on it, so that a visitor can download them. How can I do it?

I'm a newbie, and my GraphQL knowledge is really thin, I use it only to get some images to my components. My 'gatsby-config.js' contains this:

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
  options: {
    name: `documents`,
    path: `${__dirname}/src/documents`,
  },
},
```

I tried something and on GraphiQL this seems to be valid code:

```
const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query {
      document1: file(relativePath: {eq: "doc1.txt"}) {
        id
      }
    }
`)
```

But I don't know how to make that 'document1' downloadable in JSX.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is always worth looking in the [GraphiQL explorer](http://localhost:8000/___graphql) to see what is available to query. Then you can just follow the example of the static query in [the default starter's image component.](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-default/blob/master/src/components/image.js)

If you are using Gatsby > v2.1, you can do this with the [useStaticQuery](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/use-static-query/) hook.

```
import React from "react"
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby"

const Download = () => {
  const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query MyQuery {
      file(relativePath: {eq: "doc1.txt"}) {
        publicURL
        name
      }
    }
  `)
  return <a href={data.file.publicURL} download>Download {data.file.name}</a>
}

export default Download
```

If not, you can do this with [Static query](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/static-query/)

```
import React from "react"
import { StaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby"

const Download = () => (
  <StaticQuery
    query={graphql`
      query MyQuery {
        file(relativePath: {eq: "doc1.txt"}) {
          publicURL
          name
        }
      }
    `}
    render={data => <a href={data.file.publicURL} download>Download {data.file.name}</a>}
  />
)

export default Download
```